# Android singleInstance parameter

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity that can be custom by one parameter in intent (set the "type" of the activity).
The activities are all the same except title and the list histories, but same look, same data for other component of the activity/fragment thats why i create only one activity that get one parameter (= "type") from intent.
My problem is like i get only one activity declaration in manifest, i can set the lauchmode as singleInstance but what i really want is a singleInstance by "type" activity.

I don't know if i am really clear about what i want to do, if not ask me for more explanations.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Why do you want singleInstance in the first place?  It actually sounds like this is not what you want.

Comment: Create different activities for each type. To avoid duplication, create a fragment and move all your logic into that fragment and use that fragment in each activity.

Comment: @DeeV I create a system with "subapp" 3 of this was pretty similar so i create one custom activity for the home of the 3 "subapp" and what i want is to haven't 2 time in back the same home for this "subapp". Simple example i open my app in type 1 go to type 2 then go to type 1 when i back i want to return to type 2 but the next back shouldn't return to type 1 but kill my app (like a singleInstance should do it).

Comment: @Mousa i already have fragment and a lot of logic are in the fragment but i don't want to have to duplicate my activity, except if that was the only "clean" solution for do what i want to do. I think the only other solution is to override the onBack but that seems to be pretty bad for my simple use case.